# What happened to Commander Shelby after TNG episode Best of Both Worlds part II?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-eu

This is the final dialogue of the episode as well as being Shelby's last time on TNG show:

> RIKER: And Earth Station McKinley has advised they're ready to begin refitting the Enterprise.
>
> PICARD: Have they estimated time for repairs?
>
> RIKER: Five or six weeks.
>
> (doorbell)
>
> PICARD + RIKER: Come.
>
> **SHELBY: Request permission to disembark, sir.**
>
> PICARD: Permission granted. They've picked a fine officer for the task force, Commander.
>
> SHELBY: We'll have the fleet back up in less than a year. I imagine you'll get your choice of any Starfleet command, sir.
>
> RIKER: Everyone is so concerned about my next job. With all due respect, Commander, sir, my career plans are my own business, and no one else's. But it's nice to know I'll have a few options.
>
> **SHELBY: I hope I have the fortune of serving with you again, sir. Captain. 
>   (Shelby leaves)**
>
> RIKER: Course to Station McKinley ready and laid in, sir.
>
> PICARD: Make it so, Number One. ("TNG: Best of Both Worlds part II)

Is there anything in the Novels or canon or anywhere in the STU that talks about Commander Shelby and what happens to her?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Peter David gave the character a major role in his [New Frontier](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_New_Frontier) novels. She serves as Excalibur's First Officer and it is revealed that she had a romantic relationship with the ship's captain back at the academy.